# Jquery 1.4.2 ui-slider issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile 1.4.2

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

And when i loading my page on mobile chrome browser.
jquery mobile automatically create new code called "ui-slider"

Here is my original code.

```
                    <div class="product-info_image">

                        <div class="content-slider" draggable="false">
                            <div class="content-slider_viewport" >
                                <ul class="content-slider_list" id="image_wrapper" style="width: 900px;">

  <li class="content-slider_item active"  style="width: 300px;"><img src="1.gif"></li>
  <li class="content-slider_item active"  style="width: 300px;"><img src="2.gif"></li>

   </ul>
</ul>
                            </div>


                        <ol class="content-slider_pagination"><li class="content-slider_pagination_item active"></li><li class="content-slider_pagination_item"></li><li class="content-slider_pagination_item"></li></ol></div>

                    </div>
```

But when i view source on mobile chrome browser. It asserted strange code like this.

```
                    <div class="product-info_image" data-enhance="false">

                        <div class="ui-slider"> 
          <div class="content-slider ui-slider-input" draggable="false">
                            <div class="content-slider_viewport">
                                <ul class="content-slider_list" id="image_wrapper" style="width: 900px;">


                                        <li class="content-slider_item active" style="width: 300px;"><img src="1.gif"></li>                                         
    <li class="content-slider_item active" style="width: 300px;"><img src="2.gif"></li>                                         
                                </ul>
                            </div>


                        <ol class="content-slider_pagination"><li class="content-slider_pagination_item active"></li><li class="content-slider_pagination_item"></li><li class="content-slider_pagination_item"></li></ol></div><div role="application" class="ui-slider-track ui-shadow-inset ui-bar-inherit ui-corner-all"><a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-btn ui-shadow" role="slider" aria-valuemin="NaN" aria-valuemax="NaN" aria-valuenow="NaN" aria-valuetext="NaN" title="NaN" aria-labelledby="undefined-label"></a></div></div>
                                                </div>

   <div role="application" class="ui-slider-track ui-shadow-inset ui-bar-inherit ui-corner-all"><a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-btn ui-shadow" role="slider" aria-valuemin="NaN" aria-valuemax="NaN" aria-valuenow="NaN" aria-valuetext="NaN" title="NaN" aria-labelledby="undefined-label"></a></div>
```

i don't know why "ui-slider" is asserted and how can i prevent automatically created ui-slider.
I just want to use my orginal js code for sliding images.

Thanks.

Comment: Aré You using `.slider()` somewhere? Post js related to the slider.

Comment: no. i'm not using .slider()

Comment: <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--


 function fnSetInterestGoods() {
  if(window.confirm('are you sure?')){
   document._form.submit();
  }
 }

 $(function () {
  ui.contentSlider('.content-slider', {
   roll: true,
   touch: false
  });

  $(".content-slider_viewport > a").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.event-popup, .popup--dim').addClass('opened');
  })
  $(".popup_close , .popup_close--bottom a").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.event-popup, .popup--dim').removeClass('opened');
  })
 }) 
  
 
//-->
</SCRIPT>

Comment: That's all? Are you using `input` with `type=range`?

Comment: Not using type=range. And those images are not related with input

Comment: I found following script inside embeded JS. $(selector).slider($.extend({}, config, options));